# Use of **kwargs to simplify matplotlib.plot call

Tags: python, matplotlib, keyword-argument

I have to plot a long list of data (in a dataframe) with different `colors` and `markers`, and this is what I came to:

```
props = {
    'a': dict(marker='x', color='blue', alpha=.8),
    'b': dict(marker='o', color='red', alpha=.8),
    'f': dict(marker='d', color='green', alpha=.8),
    'z': dict(marker='1', color='black', alpha=.6),
}
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'config': ['z', 'b', 'a', 'f']})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == 'a'].tolist(), df[df['config'] == 'a']['value'], **props['a'])
ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == 'b'].tolist(), df[df['config'] == 'b']['value'], **props['b'])
ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == 'f'].tolist(), df[df['config'] == 'f']['value'], **props['f'])
ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == 'z'].tolist(), df[df['config'] == 'z']['value'], **props['z'])
```

I would like to simplify the last 4 lines (that seem rather not-pythonic) into a one-liner. There's this solution

```
for conf in ['a','b','f','z']: 
  ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == conf], df[df['config'] == conf]['value'], **props[conf])
```

But I was trying to get into something more compact, as:

```
 ax.plot(df.index, df['value'], **props[df['config']])
```

but I get `"Exception has occurred: TypeError unhashable type: 'Series'"`.

Is this possible?

Note: The toy example I have here is a call to `matplotlib.plot`, but I believe this type of simplification should be helpful for other code uses.

Comment: You need to write a loop: `for conf in ['a','b','f','z']: ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == conf], df[df['config'] == conf]['value'], **props[conf])`

Comment: Yes, that I already tried! (I'm going to edit the question not to induce in error). But I was thinking that there should be some way of keeping it as simple as my one-liner ´ax.plot(df.index, df['value'], **props[df['config']])´

Comment: Well, the loop is the only way. If you really want, you can write that loop into one line, either as-in, or via a loop comprehension: `[ax.plot(df.index[df['config'] == conf], df[df['config'] == conf]['value'], **props[conf])  for conf in ['a','b','f','z'] ]`.  But such a list comprehension with the only goal to create a loop, isn't considered pythonic.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you for the explanation.